# Beautiful Soup, need help scraping table in different section of same page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website which has multiple tables in different sections of the same page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.predictit.org/Contract/5367/Will-Donald-Trump-be-president-at-year-end-2018#prices"

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

table_body = soup.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

There are multiple pages on this section with different tables in each section. I am trying to scrape the prices data which is in "#prices" section but and I have specified it in URL but BeautifulSoup defaults to the table in first section "#data". Is there any way I can navigate to the section I want?

Comment: You may want to check out [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium will help when the data file isn't publicly available online (in this case, it was).

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to send request to the below URL to get the price you wish to parse. You can get that url using devtools..

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.predictit.org/PrivateData/GetPriceListAjax?contractId=5367"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for row in soup.select('table tr')[1:]:
    cols = [x.text.strip() for x in row.select('td')]
    print(cols)
```

Output:

```
['Price', 'Shares', '', 'Price', 'Shares']
['81¢', '289', '', '80¢', '2192']
['82¢', '7936', '', '79¢', '5478']
['83¢', '12800', '', '78¢', '6189']
['84¢', '8846', '', '77¢', '6167']
['85¢', '7726', '', '76¢', '2334']
['86¢', '7247', '', '75¢', '3268']
['87¢', '5562', '', '74¢', '2425']
['88¢', '4988', '', '73¢', '1390']
['89¢', '2889', '', '72¢', '3836']
['90¢', '4143', '', '71¢', '944']
```

Comment: Try and let me know if any issues you encounter. Thanks.